# How to request from specific internet adapter in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests, ip

I need to have a script making request from ethernet 1 (Internet provider 1) and another script to use ethernet 2 (Internet provider 2).

All I've been able to get was changing the socket's local IP but don't know how to use another adapter.

This is my current code.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('192.168.1.6', 0))
s.connect(('www.google.com', 80))
```

Comment: Different NIC, route or IP?

Comment: NIC, I have 2 internet providers/2 modems.

Comment: It's easy to define the source address but to which interface a packet goes is desided by your routing setup. In most cases it would be the interface with that IP but with special routings like two ISPs it might be different. And if the ISP lines are not directly connected to the computer the program runs on, it is getting even harder.